# Copy styles from `System.Windows.Controls.Button` in my custom control?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls

Ok. I am totally new to making custom controls in WPF so I need MUCH guidance. I want to make a breadcrumb button like in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/vcrumb.aspx), but this time in WPF.
I think I can figure out myself how to draw the shapes... After much hard work but now I have another concern.
I literally NEED to get and use the background brush of a standard, unaltered `System.Windows.Controls.Button` when drawing my background!

Edit:

---

Please help me out...

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Bread_Crumb_Button"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Crumb}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Crumb}">
                    <my:ButtonChrome Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}" Name="Chrome" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding Button.IsDefaulted}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding UIElement.IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding ButtonBase.IsPressed}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </my:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="my:ButtonChrome.RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="True" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="my:ButtonChrome.RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="True" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="#FFADADAD" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default style [can be found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) (there is a link "Default WPF Themes"), just need to find the right gradient in the style.

This is the default background:

```
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

Comment: This only ended up crashing my Visual Studio... :(

Comment: You need to get all the resources that the gradient references as well -_-

Comment: @Vercas: I had a somewhat misleading link, since the default styles are found on its parent site, check the updated link in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the designer, select a button, open it's properties, right click on the Template header and chose "Extract Value to Resource", then chose the destination file.

[image: Extract Template]

It will copy the default WPF Template to the destination xaml file with the key you indicated, this is usually the best starting point to overriding templates in WPF.

Comment: This looks better! I am trying it!

Comment: It is my understanding that I suck at WPF.

Comment: Wrong, for some cases it is diferent, looks like MSDN doesn't get totally updated with new WPF releases. For example combobox, what's on MSDN is actually slightly diferent then what's in the Framework.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the option to use [StyleSnooper](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/02/wpf-tools-stylesnooper/) to extract a style from a WPF control.

For runtime WPF "debugging", using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) (completely different, but genuinely awesome tool) might be helpful. When snooping an application you're developing, try pressing `Ctrl-Shift` and moving the mouse over the controls you're interested in.